# PHP fatal-error

Tags: php, fatal-error

Full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct()
[<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time
string (Next log in) at position 0 (N): The timezone could not be found in the
database' in /home/bd92/public_html/login.php:144 Stack trace:
#0 /home/bd92/public_html/login.php(144): DateTime->__construct('Next log in')
#1 {main} thrown in /home/bd92/public_html/login.php on line 144
```

This error happens on this line:

`$unbanned = new Datetime($dbunbanned);`

which goes into a database, and gets when a user is unbanned.

It then makes a Datetime so I can compare it to the current date, and see if the ban has expired, but I get this error.

Comment: You should probably say what $dbunbanned is when this error is triggered.  Better yet, you should be able to reduce your code to a very short test case that reproduces the problem.  Then you can ask about your test case.

Comment: Heres setting that, and a few other things:          $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
          $dbid = $row['user_id'];
          $dbpass = $row['password'];
          $dbuser = $row['username'];
          $dbbanned = $row['banned'];
          $dbbanreason  = $row['banreason'];
          $dbunbanned = $row['unbannedon']; then the query: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");

Comment: No, you don't need a database to reproduce this.  The error message *tells you* that the `new DateTime` call is failing.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class you must present a default timezone. If not you will recieve a fatal error.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Comment: are you adding it before you call the datetime class?